# Connect to Amazon S3 with boto3 with IAM roles

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, boto3

I am trying to shift from python boto to the newer boto3 module, for manipulating files on Amazon S3.

I also need to use Amazon IAM roles, as I did with the old boto module. I am not sure how the IAM role is set up on the server, but all I had to do is:

```
s3_conn = S3Connection()
```

and I would get access to all the buckets that the server has access to.

This seems to be different in boto3:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
     print(bucket.name)
```

I get an error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/resources/collection.py", line 83, in __iter__
  for page in self.pages():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/resources/collection.py", line 161, in pages
  pages = [getattr(client, self._py_operation_name)(**params)]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 310, in _api_call
  return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 407, in _make_api_call
  raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied
```

I am going through boto3 documentation, but I am not sure what I need to do to set up the IAM roles:

http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 7):

You will need the `s3:ListBucket` permission in your policy for all relevant buckets. You can find a full list of S3 policy conditions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html#object-keys-in-amazon-s3-policies).

Comment: How to add permission with Python Boto3 ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example of performing basic tasks in IAM using Boto3 in the code examples repository here:

[AWS IAM getting started examples](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/python/example_code/iam/iam_basics)

Comment: Always quote the most relevant part of an important link

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32726041)